# stash parsing sequence

Tags: stash

Reading through James Smith's stash tutorial and would like a little extra info on the following example, '{stash:title}' is getting set after the embed template is added (in the page sequence at least), but it works, how?

```
{embed="site/head"}
{exp:stash:set name="extra-head-data"}
    <link href="special-css-just-for-this-view.css">
{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:stash:set name="extra-foot-data"}
    <script src="special-javascript-for-single-product-views.js"></script>
{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:channel:entries limit="1" channel="products"}
    {exp:stash:set parse_conditionals="yes"}
        {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
        {stash:meta-desc}
            {if summary}
                {summary}
            {if:else}
                {exp:eehive_hacksaw words="20"}{body}{/exp:eehive_hacksaw}
            {/if}
        {/stash:meta-desc}
    {/exp:stash:set}
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    {body}
{/exp:channel:entries}
{embed="site/foot"}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is please?  `{stash:title}` is getting set because you are setting it explicitly while looking at the first element in the "products" channel... but I am guessing that this is not your question.

Comment: The embedded template 'site/head' is added before stash:title is set, stash:title is used in the 'site/head' template and is being resolved correctly, I guess the answer is that stash is called before embedding is done, it just doesn't seem intuitive and I thought embedding was done earlier in the parsing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to understand parse order better, you could have a look at this handy cheat-sheet: originally created by Low, the copy on his site appears to have disappeared, but here is a version of it from another site.

https://www.cheatography.com/adrienne/cheat-sheets/ee-parse-order/

HTH